# PythonL How to input to variable then use it to execute in another file then print to first file?

Tags: python-3.x

My first file has this code:

```
def main(self):
    age = input("Enter your age: ")
    ins = Aged()
    ins.ageplus()

main()
```

*i need to print it when main() is called in main()

```
My second file:
class Aged():
    def ageplus():
    print("Your new age is:", age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass age as an argument to `ageplus` function.

Secondly assuming your second file is called age.py.

Add `from age import Aged` at the top of your first file.